# What is the best way to create your own customized Application software center in Linux (Linux mint)?

Tags: linux, pygtk, desktop-application, pyqt5, linux-mint

Is there any way to override existing source code, shall i build from scratch in PyQt, PyGTK, Java..other?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the software itself and not the repository that it connects to, then the way to customize the application it would be to fork the project. As far as I can determine it is found at https://github.com/linuxmint/mintinstall. Assuming that's the correct repository, you would simply fork it on github, clone it to your workstation and make you changes. Then run your local copy.

Comment: Swoogan, thanks for reply. Seems you are correct about process as itself. Sorry, if I did not framed my question accurately, but In this case I was thinking more about some concrete examples of software, for example, can I use for my own project some source of app centers like AppGrid, Deepin Software Center, OS Elementary Software center.... other? Which you prefer in what case etc.... Can I use them in commercial product?